# "Setting with copy warning"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm recently new to python.  I've been trying to transform the date contents of a column into a new column containing the month and year which can the be grouped by a seaborn box plot function.   Assume `lcd_raw_clean` is a pandas dataframe containing feature `'issue_d'` which is `datetime` dtype.

The code I'm using

```
lcd_raw_clean['issue_YYMM'] = lcd_raw_clean['issue_d'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m'))
```

Generates the warning:

```
/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__main__.py:7: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I cannot understand why this generates this warning and how to get around it.

Comment: Well I can only think that `lcd_raw_clean` is a view or slice of your original df, can you post how `lcd_raw_clean` was created

Comment: > lcd_raw_clean = lcd_raw[:-4]

Comment: I  sliced the last 4 rows off as the data represented a footer.

Comment: Could you try `lcd_raw.iloc[:-4] = lcd_raw[:-4]['issue_d'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m')) `